# Roots of the complex equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all the roots for the following equation.

$2x^4-x^3-x^2+3x+1=0$

My attempt,
I factorised it to $(x+1)(2x^3-3x^2+2x+1)=0$

So I know one of its roots is -1. How to proceed then?

Comment: Please check the exercise! I think the second root should be rational.

Comment: I've checked. This question is in the complex number.

Comment: Cubic equations have analytical solutions with radicals (Cardano method). Applied to your problem, the real root is given by $$\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{183}-27}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3
   \left(2 \sqrt{183}-27\right)}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(x)=2x^3-3x^2+2x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[X]$, you can only use
numerical methods to find another solution.

The rational values which could be a root of $g(x)$ are $-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-1$ and $1$, but they are not.

You can use the newton-method, for example. Start with some approximation
$x_0=0$. Iterare

$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}$ for all $n\ge 0$.

PARI/GP gives the result :

```
? y=0;for(j=1,9,y=y-(2*y^3-3*y^2+2*y+1)/(6*y^2-6*y+2);print(y*1.0))

-0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-0.34615384615384615384615384615384615384615384615385
-0.31806102595738622882361315427324063968110852749964
-0.31718348491410616496375236986106870143867950768571
-0.31718264650753641079916661305830367484562092477196
-0.31718264650677166168414286476771118279310282662228
-0.31718264650677166168414222848912610516860235187746
-0.31718264650677166168414222848912610516860235187702
-0.31718264650677166168414222848912610516860235187702
```

All roots in the survey :

```
? f==2*x^4-x^3-x^2+3*x+1;print(polroots(f))
[-1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.E-57*I, -0.31718264650
677166168414222848912610516860235187702 + 0.E-57*I, 0.90859132325338583084207111
424456305258430117593851 - 0.86651059330735160857834104417838735323853672073107*
I, 0.90859132325338583084207111424456305258430117593851 +     0.86651059330735160857
834104417838735323853672073107*I]~
```

Comment: So how to find other real and complex solutions ?

Comment: But the complex solutions are difficult to find, so check the exercise, if there is a typo anywhere!

Comment: You could choose some other approximation to find the complex solutions or apply polynomial division, which does not work well because the second root is not a rational number.